# When remove last item from vector layer in openlayers 2, image of item stay on map

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I have a vector layer. I delete last item from layer but they stay on map. Then i add new item to layer. Last item disapear and map look right.

Comment: Please provide sample code or add a better/more extensive description of what you do. So far, this looks more like a random collection of words. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

From your description it looks like you are initializing the vector layer multiple times and loosing the reference to the actual layer object.